# dismissViewControllerAnimated doesnt load viewDidLoad again

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have tried a few things which havent really worked (more things I have thought of).

When using `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` I need it to run the `viewDidLoad` method of the controller I am going back to.

How can I do this? I thought maybe in the `completion` however, it would access the `viewDidLoad` of this class rather than of the one im resuming to.

Comment: It's the presenting view controller (The one you're going back to) that should be calling -dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: / Use delegation!

Comment: you can use viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ViewDidLoad` method is called only once. After `dismissViewControllerAnimated` is called parentViewControllers `viewWillAppear` method is called.

Write you code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Hey, is there a difference between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear?

Comment: yes viewWillAppear is called before viewDidAppear. 1st one just before view loading and 2nd after it loads completly

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Why viewWillAppear method is called on iPhone but wont call on iPad.

Comment: viewWillAppear is also called in ipad.

Answer (score 1):

viewDidLoad is only called when view is loaded into memory. You should probably use viewDidAppear. There you can even implement

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

although this doesn't seem like a good idea. Maybe you should move some of your code in viewDidLoad into a separate method?

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer here - I never knew about this method! So, I have a massive segment of code which I could put into a class or a method within the class.. So if I create a new method in this class it will still be able to access right?

Comment: This would mean that -viewDidLoad would be called twice the first time the controller is loaded. (P.S. it's -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

Comment: calling explicitly viewDidLoad anywhere from code is highly unrecommended. The better way is to extract code from viewDidLoad method into some other method.

Comment: Yes @SalmanZaidi and Moxy, I am aware of that, that's why I suggested making another method. And Josh, if you make another method in the same viewController class, it will be visible from viewDidAppear. If you make a new class, make sure it has that method in a visible interface. Also, depending on when do you want your code to be called, you can also try using (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` method would get called only if you create the object again.
You can write your code in `viewWillAppear` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Moxy's comment I believe is closest to what you're looking for. Sometimes you want a viewController to be re-loaded, as there can be methods you want run only on first load instead of every time the view will appear (in my case it was registering for notifications)

If you call:

```
      [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then your view will have ViewDidLoad called the next time it is presented.

In contrast, if you call:

```
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then your view will not call viewDidLoad when it's presented again.